# Summing multiple lists stored in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple lists stored as:

I have two dataframes as:

```
df1.ix[1:3]
DateTime      Col1     Col2 
2018-01-02    [1, 2]   [11, 21]
2018-01-03    [3, 4]   [31, 41]
```

I want to sum the lists in the df1 to get:

```
DateTime      sumCol 
2018-01-02    [12, 23]
2018-01-03    [34, 45]
```

I tried `numpy.sum(df1, axis=1)` but that causes list concatenation instead of sum.

Edit:
My original dataframe has more than 2 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this. It's a hugely inefficient way to use Pandas dataframes, as your series of lists is of dtype `object` and cannot be accessed directly by NumPy.

But, if you insist, at least partially vectorise your calculation. For instance, using NumPy:

```
arr1 = np.array(df['Col1'].values.tolist())
arr2 = np.array(df['Col2'].values.tolist())

df['Sum'] = pd.DataFrame(arr1 + arr2).values.tolist()

print(df)

     DateTime    Col1      Col2       Sum
0  2018-01-02  [1, 2]  [11, 21]  [12, 23]
1  2018-01-03  [3, 4]  [31, 41]  [34, 45]
```

Side note, `ix` has been deprecated since Pandas v0.20.0. Use `loc` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Using a list comprehension and `np.array`:

```
df.assign(sumCol=[np.array(x) + np.array(y) for x, y in zip(df.Col1, df.Col2)])
```

```
     DateTime    Col1      Col2    sumCol
0  2018-01-02  [1, 2]  [11, 21]  [12, 23]
1  2018-01-03  [3, 4]  [31, 41]  [34, 45]
```

If the arrays are always the same length:

```
df.assign(sumCol=[np.stack([x,y]).sum(0) for x, y in zip(df.Col1, df.Col2)])
```

To apply this to many columns, you can use `iloc`

```
zip(*df.iloc[:, 1:].values.T)
```

---

Here is an example on a wider DataFrame:

```
   A       B       C       D
0  1  [1, 2]  [1, 2]  [1, 2]
1  2  [3, 4]  [3, 4]  [3, 4]
2  3  [5, 6]  [5, 6]  [5, 6]
```

Using `zip` with `df.values`

```
df.assign(sumCol=[np.stack(a).sum(0) for a in zip(*df.iloc[:, 1:].values.T)])
```

```
   A       B       C       D    sumCol
0  1  [1, 2]  [1, 2]  [1, 2]    [3, 6]
1  2  [3, 4]  [3, 4]  [3, 4]   [9, 12]
2  3  [5, 6]  [5, 6]  [5, 6]  [15, 18]
```

Comment: How does "np.array(x) + np.array(y)"  get modified ?

Comment: @Zanam added an example